# Synchronously processing on knex query builder results

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, knex.js

I'm writing up a batch process to build some log type entries. It will be a separate app from my API and it will only do this one task.  Right now, I have an Express API with an endpoint that a logMsg gets delivered to. These come in from many users and each user sends one every 10 seconds or so. To keep things moving, I do a couple simple operations on that logMsg and stick it into my Postgres DB.

Now I want to iterate over those messages to build up some logEntries so that I can more easily calculate time spent during an activity. Each logMsg upon coming in, has an activity (or lack of one), a user, and a timestamp. A LogEntry has a user, activity, startTime, and endTime. That way the API application can easier calculate time spent doing/not doing activities by user or by activity for a group of users.

So I'd like to set up a batch job that grabs some n unprocessed points, marks them as in process, then processes them, then marks them as complete. Where I'm running into trouble is keeping things in order.

```
let activityLogJob = new CronJob('30 * * * * *', function() {

  return knex
    .raw() //grab a chunk of rows and mark as In Progress
    .then((processingRows) => {
        _.forEach(logMsgs, (msg) => {
            console.log('message id:', msg.id);
            return knex.select() //latest log entry for msg.user
                .then((logEntry) => {
                    if (logEntry) {
                        if (logEntry.activity_id !== msg.activity_id) {
                            console.log('new activity started. end old one');
                            return knex.transaction( (trx) => {
                                trx
                                .update() //logEntry.endTime = msg.startTime
                                .then((update) => {
                                    trx
                                    .insert(); //create new logEntry for new activity
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('first log entry for user');
                        knex
                        .insert(); //create new logEntry since we don't have one for the user
                    }
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log('finished msg :', msg.id);
                    knex
                    .update(); //set msg.status = LOGGED
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    logger.error("ERROR: ", err);
                });
        });     
    });

}, null, true);
```

So what I see with the above code is that it grabs all of the rows fine, but it gets weird when it goes to actually process them. The log statements show up like:

```
message 1
first log entry for user
message 2
first log entry for user
...
message n
first log entry for user

finished message 1
finished message 2
...
finished message n
```

So I think there's two problems going on here.
1. It never finds an existing LogEntry and creates a new one every time. That feels like the inserts aren't happening until after all the messages are processed.
2. I would have expected the log statements to be more like

```
message 1
first entry for user
finished message 1
message 2
first entry for user
finished message 2
...
```

I'm pretty sure my problem is that I'm still not wrapping my head properly around promises.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return every promise that's nested inside another promise's callback. If you don't, then the result of the nested promise won't get passed through the chain. That should help your messages sync up.

```
return knex
.raw() //grab a chunk of rows and mark as In Progress
.then((processingRows) => {
    _.forEach(logMsgs, (msg) => {
        console.log('message id:', msg.id);
        return knex.select() //latest log entry for msg.user
            .then((logEntry) => {
                if (logEntry) {
                    if (logEntry.activity_id !== msg.activity_id) {
                        console.log('new activity started. end old one');
                        return knex.transaction( (trx) => {
                            return trx #####
                            .update() //logEntry.endTime = msg.startTime
                            .then((update) => {
                                return trx #####
                                .insert(); //create new logEntry for new activity
                            });
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('first log entry for user');
                    return knex #####
                    .insert(); //create new logEntry since we don't have one for the user
                }
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('finished msg :', msg.id);
                return knex #####
                .update(); //set msg.status = LOGGED
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                logger.error("ERROR: ", err);
            });
    });     
});
```